# GooglePlayServices is not working with the project

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am working on a project where I have to authenticate a user with the Google plus and I did that. Now I have shifted my project from one PC to another for some reasons. I have made changes on developers console but when I try to login with google plus after launching, it says "Google Play Services not available. This application will close."

Why this error comes when everything is fine?

gradle dependencies is as follows:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the device (or the emulator) where you're running the app has Google Play Services installed with the latest version (currently at least 8.1.0), or set exact (earlier) version in your build.gradle.

Comment: Google Play Services is installed in my phone as they work fine with the other apps. I also tried the 2nd option which you've suggested but when I try to put a specific version pf services, it asks me to install repository and when I click to install, it says already installed. I am fed up of this :(